# Can not call class method

Tags: objective-c, class, methods

I'm building a tag-based application and want to call the same function from each tab (`ViewController`).

I'm trying to do it in the following way:

```
#import "optionsMenu.h"

- (IBAction) optionsButton:(id)sender{
   UIView *optionsView = [options showOptions:4];
   NSLog(@"options view tag %d", optionsView.tag);
}
```

`optionsMenu.h` file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface optionsMenu : UIView

- (UIView*) showOptions: (NSInteger) tabNumber;

@end
```

`optionsMenu.m` file:

```
@import "optionsMenu.h"
@implementation optionsMenu

- (UIView*) showOptions:(NSInteger) tabNumber{
   NSLog(@"show options called");

   UIView* optionsView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
   optionsView.opaque = NO;
   optionsView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5f];
   //creating several buttons on optionsView
   optionsView.tag = 100;

return optionsView;

}

@end
```

The result is that i never get the "show options called" debug message and thus `optionsView.tag` is always `0`.

What am i doing wrong?

I understand this is most probably an easy and stupid question, but i am not able to solve it myself.

Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: I'm guessing this is Objective-C. Next time, please tag your questions with the appropriate language.

Comment: Is `options` is initialized properly?

Comment: Just declared as optionsMenu* options;

Comment: You have to show us where do you instantiate "options". And, by the way, class names should start with capital letter by convention, that's "OptionsMenu" and not "optionsMenu"

Comment: Simply change your method type to `Class` method by replacing `-` with `+` thats all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing to note is that this is an instance method (and not a Class method as described in the question title). This means that in order to call this method you should have alloc/init an instance of your Class and send the message to the instance. For example:

```
// Also note here that Class names (by convention) begin with
// an uppercase letter, so OptionsMenu should be preffered
optionsMenu *options = [[optionsMenu alloc] init];
UIView *optionsView = [options showOptions:4];
```

Now, if you just want to create a Class method that returns a preconfigured `UIView`, you could try something like this (provided that you do not need access to ivars in your method):

```
// In your header file
+ (UIView *)showOptions:(NSInteger)tabNumber;

// In your implementation file
+ (UIView *)showOptions:(NSInteger)tabNumber{
    NSLog(@"show options called");

    UIView *optionsView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    optionsView.opaque = NO;
    optionsView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5f];
    //creating several buttons on optionsView
    optionsView.tag = 100;

    return optionsView;
}
```

And finally send the message like this:

```
UIView *optionsView = [optionsMenu showOptions:4]; //Sending message to Class here
```

Finally do not forget of course to add your view as a subview in order to display it.
I hope that this makes sense...